# Pushes not showing in Github and possibly wrong email set up for git config

Tags: git, github

I am having two problems and I think they might be related.

I also purchased a new machine on the weekend and I think this is causing the problem, but I'm not sure of the solution.

One is that when I am pushing to a repository the repository is being updated but no contributions are showing up in my profile.

Second, when I am doing git commit, I am getting this message:

---

Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the
following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit
your configuration file:

```
git config --global --edit
```

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

---

Is this the cause of my contribution problem?

Do I need to set these settings to anything in particular, like my github username and github email address?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me, I had to set the name and email to match the ones of my GitHub account and then it all worked fine.